# Using Perl, search and replace a number string working backwards on that string

Tags: perl

How can I do a global search and replace on a string of numbers starting from the end of the string and reading backwards?

Starting at the front of the string I can do this:

```
someword: 12345
s/someword: [0-9][0-9]/someword: ==/g;
someword: ==345
```

But that will only work if the string is five numbers long. Regardless of the length of the number string, I want to keep the last three numbers.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I should have been a little less generic. The someword:<space> <number string> comes up hundreds of times in the file and the <number string> is always different. That's why I'm using the global substitution the way I have it above.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an *executable* substitution.

This code finds multiple digits that are followed by three more digits, and replaces them with the same number of equals `=` signs

```
my $s = 'someword: 12345678';

$s =~ s/ (\d+) (?=\d{3}) / '=' x length $1 /xe;

print $s;
```

**output**

```
someword: =====678
```

Comment: Clever regex. Wonder if there is any downside for not anchoring `$` to match the last 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind):

```
my $string = 'someword: 12345';

$string =~ s/\d(?=\d{3})/=/g;

print "$string\n";
```

Outputs:

```
someword: ==345
```

Comment: I don't like the thought of that replacing one digit at a time, but I'm sure it's not a problem